# About closures returned from a constructor

Tags: javascript, closures

This question has been asked before but did not receive a definite answer, so I'll ask it again:

```
function complex(x, y) {
    return {
        real: function () {
            return x;
        },
        imaginary: function () {
            return y;
        },
        add: function (c) {
            return complex(x + c.real(), y + c.imaginary());
        }
    };
}
```

This is the skeleton of a 'complex' class, using a prototypal approach. The question is: Does every complex object created with this function have a copy of the code of the three inner functions?

Some people have said no; the interpreter/compiler will detect this situation and optimize it. Some people have said yes, a separate copy will exist in every object returned by the constructor. Some have even said that it would be impossible to do otherwise.

It seems to me it would not be impossible, as long as the 'code' of a function is kept separate from the 'context' in which the function is defined. That is, each object returned by the constructor will have three properties 'real', 'imaginary', 'add', but these properties would be special closure objects {'context', 'code'}; in any returned object 'c', 'c.real.context'==='c.imaginary.context'=== etc.; in any two objects 'c1', 'c2', 'c1.real.code'==='c2.real.code', etc.

Can anyone shed any light?

EDIT

The phrase "using a prototypal approach" above (wrong as it is) received more attention than my question: Will the CODE of each inner function be shared by the instances created by 'complex'? Clearly, each object will have different properties, c1.real !== c2.real (notice that I'm not calling real,
c1.real() may or may not be equal to c2.real()). The question is whether c1.real and c2.real will share the same CODE.

The pattern is intended as a way to keep x and y private. I just wanted to find out if it might come with a serious memory penalty, particularly in cases where the functions returned in the object are large. It means, at least, that each object has a property for each method, which may amount for a few bytes per object, per method. But, is it worse, is the CODE of each method duplicated in each object?

END EDIT

Comment: Can you add a link to the question where this was asked before?

Comment: Code are never duplicated unneccesarily by compilers.

Comment: *"using a prototypal approach"* No, not really. All you do is create an object in the function and return it. This has nothing to do with prototypal inheritance or constructor functions. While you *can* call the function with `new complex(...)`, you will get the sam behavior as you called as `complex(...)`. And I fail to see what this has to do with closures in particular.

Comment: Also it depends on what level we are talking about. If you call the function twice `a = complex(...)` and `b = complex(...)`, then `a !== b` and `a.real !== b.real`, i.e. on the JavaScript level you have two different function objects. That doesn't mean that *internally* the engine doesn't do some crazy optimization and somehow avoids to duplicate the function logic.

Comment: @FelixKling I really doubt compilers are that smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does every complex object created with this function have a copy of the code of the three inner functions?

No. Code (and bytecode to interpret) will be shared by all functions.

However, people are right when they're saying that each of your objects does contain its own 3 function objects and 1 scope structure (which holds `x` and `y`). The three methods will have to be reinstantiated for each `complex` "instance", and reference different parent scopes, but they will share their code.

Comment: Do you have any references or articles that explains it?

Comment: At least that's how V8 does it. Some reading: http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no prototypes involvment (other than `Object.prototype`) in your design. What you are currently doing is basically the same as:

```
var complexObject1 = { someFn: function () {} },
    complexObject2 = { someFn: function () {} };
```

As you can see in the above example, objects aren't sharing functions or any other members at all (except the `Object.prototype` members).

Here's how you could implement what you want with a *pure* prototypal approach.

```
var complex = {

    init: function (x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        return this;
    },

    real: function () {
        return this.x;
    },

    imaginary: function () {
        return this.y;
    },

    add: function (c) {
        return Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)).init(
            this.x + c.real(), 
            this.y + c.imaginary());
    }
};

var c1 = Object.create(complex).init(1, 2),
    c2 = Object.create(complex).init(3, 4),
    c3 = c1.add(c2);
```

However, you might be better using something more similar to a classical model with constructor functions. At least in Chrome because of [hidden classes](https://developers.google.com/v8/design).

```
function Complex(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Complex.prototype = {
    constructor: Complex,
    //other functions...
};

var c1 = new Complex(1, 2);
//...
```

Additionnaly, to shed some more light on your main question... with your approach there's no possible way to share functions between objects since the functions will rely on a closure over their parent scope to access the `x` and `y` variables. You cannot switch the closure scope of a function at execution time. There could be some compiler optimizations, however in this specific situation I doubt the compiler would be smart enough to create a single function instance internally and invoke it with intended scope when called.

Comment: What happened to `C = function(){}` + `C.prototype.add = function(){}`? =( Is that not cool anymore?

Comment: @Rudie Yeah, I updated the answer. Not only it's still cool but it's perhaps more efficient because of the way constructor functions are treated.

Comment: @HerrSerker Which one is the first? You mean the one with `Object.create`? Of course it is. `Object.create` explicitely sets up the prototype chain.

Comment: @HerrSerker: It is. `Object.create` creates a new object which inherits from the argument.

Comment: @FelixKling But your methods are not

Comment: @HerrSerker: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @HerrSerker Me neither...?

Comment: You typed your first approach would be _pure_ prototypal. But the methods in your object do not belong to the prototype of that object. They belong to the object itself. So every instance of the object will have copies of those methods. That is not _pure_ prototypal, but half prototypal.

Comment: @HerrSerker I think you misunderstand these concepts. `Object.create(complex)` returns a new object that has it's internal prototype link set to point to `complex`. In other words it creates instances of `complex` objects. These objects all share the same functions. Check it yourself `var o = { fn: function () {} }, o1 = Object.create(o), o2 = Object.create(o); o1.fn === o2.fn;`

Comment: Maybe you are right. This concept differs a bit from the prototypal approach I learn several years (or eons) ago. But I still think it's not prototypal. And as I guess you cannot have private functions or members.

Comment: @HerrSerker Well you could have private members using the module pattern, just like you would with a classical model and the `init` function is the same as a constructor here, so you could also have priviledged functions. `Object.create` almost just an alterntive to the `new` keyword. Both models are equally powerful and yes, they are prototypal.

Comment: Do you have any web ressource where I can read more about it?

Comment: plaix: My motivation was to keep x and y private. I understand your approach, and it is more memory efficient, but x and y are public now.

Comment: @user1751673 Oh ok. Well I wouldn't put too much effort on enforcing true privacy for instanciable *classes*. Using a naming convention like `this._myPrivateVar` is in my opinion, far more appropriate since it doesn't prevent you to write memory-efficient code. For modules that's another story however.